# Sencha Touch: how to set slider and container on one horizontal line?

Tags: sencha-touch

I jsut can't set up two things side by side correctly. Help me, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erhm, be a little more specific as to what you want.
You can always add two items next to each other by adding a wrapper panel with a hbox layout:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: 'left',
        width: 100
    },{
        xtype: 'sliderfield',
        name: 'myslider',
        flex: 1
    }]
}
```

hope it helps